# Interval sets subset complements question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A and B be sets in some universal set U

$$A^c \times B^c \subseteq (A \times B)^c$$

I'm having trouble with this problem. Here is what I have so far, can someone point me in the right directions. Many thanks. Note that c represents the complement.

$$(x, y) \in A^c \times B^c$$
$$x \in A^c \space and \space y \in B^c$$
$$x \notin A \space and  \space y \notin B$$

What would be the appropriate next step?

Edit:

Here is my proof, I'm not sure if this is rigorous enough, but please let me know. Picking off from where I left off,

If $x \notin A$ and $y \notin B$ implies $x \notin (A \times B)$. However, the converse is not true.

Thus, $x \in (A \times B)^c$

Comment: "$x\notin A$ and $y\notin B$" implies that "$x\notin A$ **or** $y\notin B$". Try to also work out what it means for $(x,y)$ to be an element of $(A\times B)^c$. (and I believe you mean $y\notin B$, in the last line)

Comment: Thank you for spotting the error. Also, why do you say " ∉  and  ∉ " implies that " ∉  or  ∉ ". If that is the case, wouldn't it possible for (x,y) ∈ ^ x  to be true?

Comment: $A^c$ doesn't mean anything until you specify a universal set containing $A$. Once you do that for $A$ (and for $B$, and for $A\times B$), you should be able to reason your way through it.

Comment: Thanks, I made sure to add that into the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I meant in the comments:

---

$(x,y)\in A^c\times B^c\quad$ if and only if $\quad x\in A^c$ and $y\in B^c\quad$ if and only if $\quad x\notin A$ **and** $y\notin B$.

$(x,y)\in(A\times B)^c\quad$ if and only if $\quad(x,y)\notin A\times B\quad$ if and only if $\quad x\notin A$ **or** $y\notin B$.

---

Hence $(x,y)\in A^c\times B^c$ implies $(x,y)\in(A\times B)^c$, because $(x\notin A$ **and** $y\notin B)$ implies $(x\notin A$ **or** $y\notin B)$

Comment: Ohh wow, that is interesting. Is that De Morgan's law for you to be able to make the jump from and to or in (,)∉ × <-> ∉ or ∉? Anyways, thanks for the clarification! Your proof is definitely easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, exactly: $(x,y)\notin A\times B$ iff not $(x,y)\in A\times B$ iff not ($x\in A$ and $y\in B$) iff $x\notin A$ or $y\notin B$. In fact, De Morgan's laws work perfectly fine in set notation, where $\cup$ is onderstood as "or", $\cap$ is understood as "and" and the complement $(\cdot)^c$ is understood as "not". This is because the subsets of a universal set $U$ form a [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)